# Div with the heigh of 100% extends beyond the visible area of the page

Tags: html, css

Seems to be a very basic concept but I do not understand why when I set the div's height to 100% it extends beyond the visible area of the page. My page is like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" style="height: 100%;">
<head></head>

<body style="height: 100%;"> 
 <div style="height: 100%; background-color: red">&nbsp;</div>
</body>

</html>
```

When I open it in the browser, the browser adds a vertical scroller to the page and my div extends beyond the bottom:

[image]

If I scroll down a little, I do see the bottom of the div:

[image]

But why does my div with the height of 100% extends beyond the bottom of the page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a default margin for the body in most browser stylesheets which causes this. You can reset the margin as shown below

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" style="height: 100%;">

<head></head>

<body style="height: 100%;">
  <div style="height: 100%; background-color: red">&nbsp;</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: where is this "default margin for the body in most browser stylesheets" stored?

Comment: In the browser's own stylesheet, which you actually never get to see. But if you use the browser developer tools, there is a tab named "calculated styles" or similar, and there (at least in Firefox, but most likely also in other browsers) is a checkbox "browser styles" which (also) shows the browser styles in the list of the different elements. Please note that I can't describe this 100% accurately since it will be different on every browser and in every language

Comment: some browsers will also let you see that stylesheet - open the developer tools and look for a tab called "styles" or similar. As I said, hard to describe accurately...

Comment: Perfect. Thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 2):

That's because there is a default margin on the body when using code snippets on SO. I don't know if your problem is with code snippets only, but generally speaking, you probably have some `margin` (or `padding` or similar) around some element, which pushes the `div` down.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US" style="height: 100%;">

<head></head>

<body style="height: 100%;">
  <div style="height: 100%; background-color: red">&nbsp;</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. Your fix worked. Your comment about this being the problem on SO is not correct though. I tested this in the browser on my machine and not on SO.

Comment: Right. Thankfully Johannes saw the bigger picture though :)

Answer (score 0):

/!Array.prototype.find&&Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,"find",{value:function value(predicate){if(null==this)throw new TypeError(""this" is null or not defined");var o=Object(this),len=o.length>>>0;if("function"!=typeof predicate)throw new TypeError("predicate must be a function");for(var thisArg=arguments[1],k=0;k<len;){var kValue=o[k];if(predicate.call(thisArg,kValue,k,o))return kValue;k++}},configurable:!0,writable:!0}),!Array.prototype.findIndex&&Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,"findIndex",{value:function value(predicate){if(null==this)throw new TypeError(""this" is null or not defined");var o=Object(this),len=o.length>>>0;if("function"!=typeof predicate)throw new TypeError("predicate must be a function");for(var thisArg=arguments[1],k=0;k<len;){var kValue=o[k];if(predicate.call(thisArg,kValue,k,o))return k;k++}return-1},configurable:!0,writable:!0}),!Array.prototype.includes&&Object.defineProperty(Array.prototype,"includes",{value:function value(searchElement,fromIndex){function sameValueZero(x,y){return x===y||"number"==typeof x&&"number"==typeof y&&isNaN(x)&&isNaN(y)}if(null==this)throw new TypeError(""this" is null or not defined");var o=Object(this),len=o.length>>>0;if(0===len)return!1;for(var n=0|fromIndex,k=Math.max(0<=n?n:len-Math.abs(n),0);k<len;){if(sameValueZero(o[k],searchElement))return!0;k++}return!1}}),"function"==typeof this.Promise&&!this.Promise.prototype.finally&&Object.defineProperty(Promise.prototype,"finally",{value:function value(onFinally){return this.then(onFinally,onFinally)}}),"function"==typeof this.Promise&&"function"!=typeof this.Promise.allSettled&&Object.defineProperty(Promise,"allSettled",{value:function value(promises){let promiseResults=promises.map(p=>Promise.resolve(p).then(val=>({status:"fulfilled",value:val}),err=>({status:"rejected",reason:err})));return Promise.all(promiseResults)},writable:!0,configurable:!0}),"function"!=typeof Object.assign&&Object.defineProperty(Object,"assign",{value:function assign(target,varArgs){'use strict';if(null===target||target===void 0)throw new TypeError("Cannot convert undefined or null to object");for(var nextSource,to=Object(target),index=1;index<arguments.length;index++)if(nextSource=arguments[index],null!==nextSource&&void 0!==nextSource)for(var nextKey in nextSource)Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(nextSource,nextKey)&&(to[nextKey]=nextSource[nextKey]);return to},writable:!0,configurable:!0}),"function"!=typeof Object.fromEntries&&Object.defineProperty(Object,"fromEntries",{value:entries=>[...entries].reduce((hash,entry)=>(hash[entry[0]]=entry[1],hash),{})});

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.